# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.1 is not supported

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This Django project is working before I created another Django project on my computer. But today when I run the project it shows error message like that=>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114,
in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in
__getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "Users..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d.%d is not supported." % VERSION[:3])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.1 is not supported.
```

What is mean Django 3.0.1 is not supported?

Comment: Have you tried updating your Python? There have been a few issues with older Python versions and Django 3.

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Comment: @VaibhavMishra, 3.7.3

Comment: @MatthewGaiser, How can I update python version? I just install now python 3.8. but when I type python it sill show 3.7.3.

Comment: Can you please create virtualenv using python3.7.3 then install Django3 inside virtualenv. Because Django3 support only Python3.6 and upper. Maybe some python version compatibility issue is there.

Comment: for python version change please  follow this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: @VaibhavMishra, I am not using the same environment.I am not clear what u said.

Comment: I am just saying please confirm Django using Python3.7.3 or not.

Comment: @Loran the error is coming from your sql server package. What is the pyodbc package you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sql_server package you're using isn't compatible with Django 3.0 or higher. It's not clear from your question which sql_server package you're using (is it django-pyodbc?) but most of the packages haven't added support for Django 3.0 yet.

Use a version of Django that is compatible with you django-pyodbc package (consult the documentation of the package, probably you should be using Django 2.1 or 2.2) or fork the package and modify it to support Django 3.0.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, I use django-pyodbc-azure 2.1 and I guess my old project uses Django 2.1. My new one is trying to use Django-channels and that one needs Django>=2.2, That's why its was install Django 3.0. Now I just downgrade to Django 2.1 and Its work now.

Comment: `django-mssql-backend` is the fork of `django-pyodbc-azure` that supports Django 2.2 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is due to installing different version for your new project.you should use a different virtual environment for each project to avoiding this problems.

Answer (score -3):

Can you please create virtualenv using python3.7.3 then install Django3 inside virtualenv. Because Django3 support only Pyth on3.6 and upper. Maybe some python version compatibility issue is there. for python version change please follow this link .. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: This has nothing to do with the python version, as you can see OP is running  python 3.7.