# How to connect Django database to Sql server?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I hope you are doing well.

I have recently started learning django and it has been going great. However, there is a problem I am facing. I am having difficulties to connect it to the Sql database. I have read some of the previous threads and most of the people were suggesting to use "pyodbc" as a library. However, it appears that this library is not compatible with the new versions of python and django. After filling in the database information, I am getting the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.3 is not
>   supported.

I have tried a combination of different python, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure versions but none of them seems to be working. Moreover, when I run the code in the terminal it works and connect to the database. Hence, I wanted to know whether there is a workaround for this problem? Or am I missing something obvious?

```
 DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'xxxxx',
    'HOST': '111.111.1.111',
    'USER': 'abc',
    'PASSWORD': "bca",
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        #'driver': 'SQL Server',
        'unicode_results': True,
    },
},
```

}

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the django-pyodbc-azure docs: "Supports Django 2.1". BTW I had to use SQL Server with Django in a project some years ago. Can't recommend it.

Comment: django-pyodbc-azure and django 2.1 should work. Not ideal, since django 2.1 isn't supported anymore, but no other choice if you use SQL Server. I would recommend to use a different database with Django. Switch to postgresql.

Comment: Searching for *pyodbc django 2.2* brings up the fork [django-mssql-backend](https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/), which says it supports Django 2.2 and Django 3.0. It might be better to stick with Django 2.2, since it will be supported until after the next LTS 3.2 is released.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 3.0.1 is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540299/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-django-3-0-1-is-not-supported)